# Отправка письма с вложениями

Tags: php, html, email, css

Всем привет!

Столкнулся с задачей отправлять письма клиентам, но с определенными условиями.

1. Отправлять HTML в письме
2. Отправлять картинки, содержащиеся в письме вместе с письмом
3. Если возможно, то и CSS, чтобы все это красиво читалось

В итоге:

1. Решено
2. Нет
3. Нет

Картинки, соответственно, которые в html разметке, должны браться из аттача.
Просто как-то никто не сталкивался из знакомых с этим.

И может есть где или вы сами видели правила для оформления html для писем.

Comment: Скачай RoundCube и пошурши по коду!

Comment: Эхех... жесть... ну поползаю.
просто поменьше кода хочется. ковырять готовую большую штуку как обычно жестоко.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. -
2. [How to embed images in html email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1851728/how-to-embed-images-in-html-email). Если вкратце, то приаттаченным картинкам нужно добавить заголовок `Content-ID`, а в HTML в качестве src у картинки указать `cid:content-id-соответствующей-картинки`
3. CSS в письмах запрещен.

Пример письма со вложением:

```
To: Vasya <vasya@pupkin.ru>
From: Example.Com <admin@example.com>
Subject: Image Embedded Test
Content-Type: multipart/related;
 boundary="=_5830a5e2a54f00a05267558b87c46967"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
Content-Disposition: inline

This is a message in Mime Format.  If you see this, your mail reader does not support this format.

--=_5830a5e2a54f00a05267558b87c46967
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
Content-Disposition: inline

<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<a href="http://example.com/"><img src="cid:5b2e7c4e0039fe369a8eb443139e8565"></a>

<h1>Hello, Vasya!</h1>
--=_5830a5e2a54f00a05267558b87c46967
Content-Type: image/gif
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-ID: <5b2e7c4e0039fe369a8eb443139e8565>
Content-Disposition: inline; filename="logo.gif"

R0lGODlh2wBQANUAAMwAAOmMjNk4OPfOztYZGeJoaPG1td5RUfrm5tIQEO6lpdcqKtAICOZ7

... далее base64 картинки

pWiaDKgBOCACJ/CasAmbJDB1t3kuQQAAOw==
--=_5830a5e2a54f00a05267558b87c46967--
```

Comment: Именно Content-Type: **multipart/related** и обратите внимание на Content-ID: <5b2e7c4e0039fe369a8eb443139e8565> в части письма с картинкой. Точно такой должна быть ссылка из text/html.

Откровенно скажу, не знаю есть ли в PHP функции для формирования письма, но "руками" такие части компоновать надо так. Это из rfc2387, а основные rfc по MIME 2045 и 2046.

Скорее всего, я опоздал с этим материалом (раньше на глаза вопрос не попался), но вдруг будет полезным.

Answer (score -1):

Как я понял картинки встроены в саму разметкку (в html код)? Если так, то просто в атрибуте src прописывать полный путь, т.е. `src='http://yoursite.com/..../yourimage.jpg'` и разумеется картинки будут тянуться с вашего сервера.
Ну а с css также, просто вставлять инлайновые стили к тэгам, например `<p style='color:#222; font-weight:bold'></p>` и тогда все будет как вам нужно.

Comment: Мне не нужно тащить картинки с сервака я их оттуда удаляю после отправки письма, ибо разослать 10К писем и к каждому иметь по 300Кб картинок, место на серваке кушается хорошо.

Вопрос не стоит о взятии картинки с сервака, а именно в приаттачивании их к письму.

Comment: Значит вникать нужно вот здесь: http://phpclub.ru/detail/article/mail#part_2

Comment: не-не-не Девид Блейн не-не-не